# Marshaling complex data types between .NET and COM

Tags: .net, com-interop

I have spent the last day or so writing a simple control library in VB.NET to be used in an existing vb6 project.  I have most things working; my controls show up in the vb6 toolbox, events work, etc.  My current problem is trying to deal with passing complex objects between vb6 and .NET.

For example, the Font property of a .NET TextBox.  Now, vb6 uses stdFont objects and .NET (obviously) uses the System.Drawing.Font type.  My goal with this project is to make the change transparent from the vb6 side.  I would like to completely emulate the vb6 interface for each control to minimize the code that needs to change when we add the new controls in, but I am stuck here.  Here is an example (.NET):

```
Public Overloads Property Font() As stdole.StdFont
    Get                        
        Return ???
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As stdole.StdFont)
        Dim style As FontStyle = GetFontStyle(value)
        TextBox1.Font = New Font(value.Name, value.Size, style, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, value.Charset)
    End Set
End Property
```

As you can see, the 'getter' is the problem.  How can I mimic the vb6 interface here if I cannot return the textbox's Font property?  I don't want to return a stdFont copy of the System.Drawing.Font for obvious reasons.

Now, I could just add methods like SetBold(), SetItalic(), and SetFont() (or boolean properties like "FontIsBold"), but this is exactly what I am trying to avoid.  My interop experience is fairly minimal, so any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was happy to see your answer... but I think I'm missing something.  I followed the instructions in the link to msdn that you provided, and on the VB6 side, I have access to the font properties on the UserControl, but when I try to (say) set the font size, it doesn't affect the way the text is drawn.  And when I try to force a change to font size on the embedded TextBox on the VB.Net side (in the Set Text property), I get an error saying that font.size is ReadOnly...

Is a working example available?

Comment: Now see that on the VB6 side, you have to Set an entire font object back onto the UserControl, can't just change a property on the font.